# script task in SSIS under for loop each container takes lot of time to complete

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task, foreach-loop-container

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiB0s.png)I need to execute a c# code for each record which i get from a table

I pass these records using for each loop container in SSIS . Which calls the script task for each record.

In the script task i have a c# code which executes some logic and loads the results into another table.

When i do it, i can see all the data loaded into table faster.
But the whole process is not completed . Package is takes 2 hrs of time to show successful.

What could be the reason for this ?
howwe can solve this

i tried closing the db connection for each record when it inserts into the table

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string query = "insert into [TEMP_PRE_STG](id,addressType,country,STATUS) values(id,@addressType,@country,@STATUS)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZGPFTGID", Dts.Variables["User::hid"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressline", address);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group1", Dts.Variables["User::group1"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group2", 
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

package should complete faster after loading the data into table.

Comment: Whats the size of data that you are updating? And why not use execute sql task to perform updates?

Comment: there are 160000 records from source which i send to script task  .                            I used execute sql task also and it took the same time to close

Comment: When I used execute sql task, it is slow when compared to just putting the insert into the C# code

Comment: The issue is resolved. I have created a dataflowtask and inside that script component is called . this has improved the performance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. I have created a dataflowtask and inside that script component is called . this has improved the performance